# How to multiply weighted value to matrix in keras?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I have two vectors, `weighted: shape (None, 3)` and `D: shape (None, 3, 5)`. Then I want to multiply `weighted` to `D` like `weighted * D: shape(None, 3, 5)`.
I attached my image below. So each scalar value is multiplied to each row element.

So I tried `multiply([weighted, D])`, but I got an error `ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3, 5) (3,)`. I assume this is caused of different shape of inputs. Then, how do I fix this?

[image]

### Update

`multiply([weighted, Permute((2, 1))(D)])` worked. I am not sure but last element of shape must be same..

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape `weighted` and use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to accomplish that. Like this:

```
weighted = weighted.reshape(-1, 3, 1)
result = weighted * D
```

**Update 1:** The same concept (broadcasting) can be used for instance in tensorflow with `tf.expand_dims(weights, dim=2)`. My POC:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.reset_default_graph()

anp = np.array([[1, 2, 10], [2, 1, 10]])
bnp = np.random.random((2, 3, 5))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    weighted = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))
    D = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3, 5))

    rweighted = tf.expand_dims(weighted, dim=2)
    result = rweighted * D

    r = sess.run(result, feed_dict={weighted: anp, D: bnp})

    print(bnp)
    print("--")
    print(r)
```

For keras use the backend API:

```
from keras import backend as K
...
K.expand_dims(weighted, 2)
```

Comment: I should say these are not numpy array, Tensor.

Comment: oh.. I see, the same still applies, but is a bit different, let me change my answer